# Prevent caching some selected parts of a html page

Tags: caching

I've written a small block in php (used drupal) and have enabled caching because the page contains several static images. But I don't want contents of the block to be cached.

Tried to use **[Cache_Lite](http://pear.php.net/package/Cache_Lite/redirected)** but it's not working. So is there a way to restrict some parts of the page prevent being cached?

thanks in advance...

Comment: is that block contains images?

Comment: No, that particular block doesn't contain any image.
It's just some text based thing. Bit like a shopping cart thing. the component has items that the user selects.

Comment: Use JavaScript to update that Portion ,because as far as i know it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [ESI](http://drupal.org/project/esi). In short you need to AJAX load that block if you don't wish for it be be cached for logged out users.